# Mysterious hidden .lb-file

Tags: auxiliary-files

I have all my important LaTeX-Files in a `git` repository. Therefore I noticed when a new hidden(!) auxiliary(?) file appeared while working on my TeX-files. The filename is `.<tex-filename>.lb`.
Here are the facts:

- The file started to appear just recently. Because of this I guess it was caused by an update to some part of (La)TeX (I update my 2014-MacTeX-distribution roughly every week).
- I even get this on simple files (see below)
- It doesn't matter, whether I compile with `XeLaTeX` or `pdfLaTeX`
- The log file has nothing suspicious in it.

If I compile this file `test.tex` with `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

I get the following `.test.lb`-file:

```
(dp0
S'engine'
p1
Vpdflatex
p2
sS'packages'
p3
c__builtin__
set
p4
((lp5
tp6
Rp7
sS'files_with_guttermarks'
p8
g4
((lp9
S'test.tex'
p10
atp11
Rp12
sS'synctex'
p13
I01
s.
```

Some basic informations about the file are listed and if I include some packages their names also appear in this file. The funny thing: Even the names of packages, that are not loaded (`\ifXeLaTeX... \else ...`) appear!

Does anybody know, what `.lb`-files are and what's creating them?

Comment: What editor do you use? Or is this at the command line?

Comment: I use TextMate2 together with Skim. I am going to try command line as soon as possible … completely forgot to check that.

Comment: Ha! Compliling via Terminal does NOT produce .lb-files! Therefore `syncTeX` is probably the cause. I will update my `.gitignore` accordingly now. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I going to leave this open for now … maybe there is someone with deeper knowledge of `syncTeX` who can elaborate on this matter.

Comment: Is `syncTeX` different from `--synctex`? I use the latter and don't have `.lb` files...

Comment: Also using TextMate 2 and Skim. I was compiling a dtx file, but the same mysterious `.<nameoffile>.lb` appeared.